# How can I find all of Spree's default files?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, spree

I'm reading up on customization sections and they give very good examples, but no where do they seem to mention the location of the fallback code in the case that we do not override.  I want to look at the original code on my machine, and I'm assuming it has to be somewhere, just not in my application directory.  Where do I go to find this? I'm new to Ruby and using RVM, if that matters.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So apparently it's located within the gems folder within rvm.  You can get there by doing

```
cd $(rvm gemdir)
```

By using

```
find ./spree* -ifile "*.extension"
```

you can find all the relevant files that spree provides by default.